# Filtros dinâmicos utilizando lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma tabela

> ErrosProducao_Registros

que tem ligação com uma outra tabela chamada

> ErrosProducao_Tipos.

Preciso realizar filtros dinâmicos na tabela ErrosProducao_Registros utilizando expressões lambda.

se eu realizo os filtros assim:

```
List<ErrosProducao_Registros> list = db.ErrosProducao_Registros.ToList();

//filtra o tipo de erro
if (codTipoErro >= 0)
    list = list.Where(e => e.CodTipoErro == codTipoErro);
```

minha variavel list ainda tem todos os dados da tabela ErrosProducao_Tipos pela relação do banco, porem, tenho dúvida quanto a performance utilizando este método.

Hoje faço como abaixo:

```
using (DB_VISTA_RECORTEEntities db = new DB_VISTA_RECORTEEntities())
{
    IQueryable<ErrosProducao_Registros> result = db.ErrosProducao_Registros;

    //filtra o tipo de erro
    if (codTipoErro >= 0)
       result = result.Where(e => e.CodTipoErro == codTipoErro);

    List<ErrosProducao_Registros> list = result.ToList();
}
```

Porem dessa ultima forma demonstrada já não tenho acesso ao objeto da tabela ErrosProducao_Tipos.

Como devo proceder?

Comment: Já tentou usar um `Include`?, ou então na `Select` buscar o que precisa? a Segunda maneira é a ideal, porque só traz aquilo que precisa da suas tabelas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto a perfomance continue usando o `IQueryable`, pois dessa forma com certeza será mais rápido que o primeiro exemplo pois o filtro será feito no banco dados, enquanto no primeiro será feito em memória com todos os registros já retirados do banco de dados.

Basta usar o `Include`. Adicione `using System.Data.Entity` pois tem um método Include em outro namespace, no `System.Linq` se não me engano.

```
using (DB_VISTA_RECORTEEntities db = new DB_VISTA_RECORTEEntities())
{
    IQueryable<ErrosProducao_Registros> result = db.ErrosProducao_Registros.Include(e => e.ErrosProducao_Tipos);

    //filtra o tipo de erro
    if (codTipoErro >= 0)
       result = result.Where(e => e.CodTipoErro == codTipoErro);

    List<ErrosProducao_Registros> list = result.ToList();
}
```

Porém você pode trabalhar com o LazyLoading, é um pouco chato de entender, mas o Include já irá resolver.

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx